# What is $set in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I am coding along with some MongoDB tutorial. I came across this.

```
const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      {
        $set: req.body,
      },
      { new: true }
    );
```

What exactly is $set? I think it is used to set anything from `req.body` to the DB, but I want to see some documentation about it and other `$` use cases. However, I cannot find any documentation about `$set`.

Comment: You mean https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because simple question for documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The $set operator replaces the value of a field with the specified value.**

This means that when u update some data, u can set the values of specific fields, even if those fields do not exist yet.

Here is all information u need: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

> "If the field does not exist, $set will add a new field with the
> specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type
> constraint. If you specify a dotted path for a non-existent field,
> $set will create the embedded documents as needed to fulfill the
> dotted path to the field."